# How to prevent user to access other users' data?

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, data-structures, architecture

**PROBLEM**

- User authenticated into the application
- Simple database schema: User ---> Document ---> Item
- API to access to Document Items

If the logged user knows the id of items that belong to some other user, he can access to it.
I would like to prevent this behavior.

**SOLUTION**

The first solution I found is to add a userid field to every records in every table to check at every query if the record belong to the logged user.

This is a good solution? Do you know some better design pattern to prevent the user to access other users' data?

Thanks

Comment: You should not be allowing users to input their "ID" as parameters. That should be stored in session or other internal data store and should not be allowed to edit it.

Comment: I think the better solution is: I store the user Id in session and I add the field user id for every table. So that at every query I can check the ownership of the record

Comment: You don't have to change the the way you store data to achieve this. I'm not sure which database you're using.. look into using a view instead of changing the schema.

Comment: I'm using a NOSql database

Comment: I see now why you were preferring adding UserId to every Item. I'm not sure if NOSql is the right tool for such architecture but I'm no expert in that regard. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the documents belong to a user, adjust your queries so that only items that belong to the user's documents are retrieved. No need to add userIDs to the items themselves.
2. If you *need* to expose IDs to the users, make those IDs GUIDs, instead of consecutive numbers. While not a perfect solution, it makes it much harder to guess the IDs of other users' items,
3. If you're using Oracle, there's VPD, Virtual Private Database. You can use that to restrict access for users.

Comment: I disagree with using GUIDs for this. Just don't expose SQL IDs outside of the system. It should be an internal field. But I understand this is probably a bigger change than you're looking for.

Comment: I have to expose the record id because the object are loaded at different time

Comment: @samyi Noted and addressed in answer.