# How to prevent access of other user's data in a database

Tags: database, security, authentication

Let's say a user is logged into an application and wants to retrieve some data associated with their profile. The application does a REST call with their user ID to the backend, which in turn does an SQL query (SELECT x FROM y WHERE user_id = '...').

The problem here is that if I know someone else's user ID, I can intercept the REST call and insert their ID into it, thereby accessing their data.

How can this problem be avoided?

(This question is very similar to [How to prevent user to access other users' data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091954/how-to-prevent-user-to-access-other-users-data), but it's been 5 years so I figured I'd give it another go)

Answer (score 0):

So in this scenario you have an encryption in a particular logarithm to send userid and decrypt it on REST service application before using it in USERID column in the backend.
Another possible solution is to encrypt both the column value and userid value passed in REST url !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into it!